# When looking at cloud cover predictions for landscape photography, should I select my location or that of the distant mountains?

Tags: landscape, weather, sunrise, clouds

I am photographing mountains 50 miles away. If I want predict cloud cover — I'm looking for low clouds for sunrise — which location should I choose?

Should I choose where I am standing, or the cloud cover forecast for the mountains 50 miles away?

Comment: This is highly dependent on your exact location. Also, why don't you simply use satellite images and/or your local weather forecast agency's data? They definitely will be more precise than a layman's quick view in the sky.

Comment: Hmm; that other question doesn't really address this specific thing.

Comment: @mattdm yes I agree, I think this is a good question and distinct from the other one

Comment: I also agree as well. This question is about what weather prediction to look at when photographing a mountain (the one over the mountain or the one where you are). The other question is about what is the right amount of cloud coverage.

Comment: @Sachin Could you give an example of the kind of results you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the clouds to be in your photograph, check cloud coverage for where you want the clouds to be. This may be between you and the mountains, directly over the mountains, or beyond the mountains. Cloud coverage over the camera is unlikely to appear in frame unless you are pointing the camera straight up.

If you have some other reason for wanting clouds to be directly above the camera, check cloud coverage for the camera's position.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the weather forcast for your shooting location and every other location that will be within the camera's field of view. Who says you can check the forecast for only a single location?